# Virtual Machine Introspection for VirtualBox

Tags: operating-systems, virtualization, oracle

Is possible use Virtual Machine Introspection (VMI) for monitoring system calls and internal system operations in Oracle VirtualBox machine (if I use Linux as quest system) in this time? I have read few research papers about VMI, but unfortunately these projects are dead today... I know about LibVMI project, but it does not have support for VirtualBox. I would use it for monitoring of high-interaction honeypot.

Thanks for replies...

Comment: I see that you used the `honeypot` tag but don't seem to mention honeypots in your question. Is the tag incorrect or are honeypots somehow relevant? You should probably [edit your question](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/104285/edit) to clarify.

Comment: @NeilSmithline tag is relevant I edited this yet.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with VirtualBox, but you can take a look at http://drakvuf.com/ for an example on how such monitoring could work using Xen.

Comment: @buherator thanks it looks amazing, but it supports only windows as quest system, do you know something similar with support Linux as quest system please?

Comment: @Mato Unfortunately I don't. But I think DRAKVUF can give you some insight about how such a system should work. Maybe you can even reuse some code after implementing kernel symbol parsing.

Comment: [nitro](https://github.com/pfohjo) is a KVM based solution which should be OS agnostic at a certain degree.

Answer (score 1):

you should check the [Winbagility](https://github.com/Winbagility/Winbagility) project which provides the VMI APIs for VirtualBox (called FDP for *Fast Debugging Protocol*).

A library similar to libvmi has been written on top of it:
[icebox](https://github.com/thalium/icebox).

I don't believe that they will make a libvmi driver for FDP.
The reason is that they used VirtualBox because it is a cross-platform hypervisor, so no need to be compatible with other hypervisors.

It's a late response, but it may help someone.